# Border Pane issues

Tags: javafx, border, gridpane, pane, hbox

I want to make a border pane with two HBoxes on top and bottom and a GridPane in the center... I wrote what I needed, attached the labels but I can't run the code 
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException is what I get as an error... the code is below, any help is welcome :) thanks

```java
public class labelBorder extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setPrefSize(400, 400);

        HBox hb1 = new HBox();
        Label lb1 = new Label("");
        lb1.setPrefWidth(200);
        lb1.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.AQUAMARINE,BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,null,new BorderWidths(5))));
        Label lb2 = new Label("");
        lb2.setPrefWidth(200);
        lb2.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLUEVIOLET,BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID,null,new BorderWidths(5))));


        HBox hb2 = new HBox();
        URI foto = Paths.get("D:\\Barca.jpg").toUri();
        Label lb3 = new Label();
        lb3.setGraphic(new ImageView(foto.toString()));
        lb3.autosize();

        GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        Label lb4 = new Label("");
        Label lb5 = new Label("");
        Label lb6 = new Label("");
        Label lb7 = new Label("");

        gp.add(lb4, 0, 0);
        gp.add(lb5, 0, 1);
        gp.add(lb6, 1, 0);
        gp.add(lb7, 1, 1);

        gp.getChildren().addAll(lb4,lb5,lb6,lb7);           
        hb1.getChildren().addAll(lb1,lb2);
        hb2.getChildren().addAll(lb3);


        bp.setTop(hb1);
        bp.setCenter(gp);
        bp.setBottom(hb2);
        bp.getChildren().addAll(hb1,hb2,gp);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: .. and don't forget to add the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You should *NOT* add the duplicate children controls to your parent layout(pane). Your code must be throwing,

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added

To overcome your issue remove these lines,

```
gp.getChildren().addAll(lb4,lb5,lb6,lb7);
```

And,

```
bp.getChildren().addAll(hb1,hb2,gp);
```

As those controls have already been added to your corresponding layout.

> Note: Adding children with `pane.getChildren().addAll(...)` on BorderPane is irrelevant and will be ignored while rendering the added controls.

Comment: Just saw it, and removed the line....still the code won`t execute... I made sure the build path is right and the module build path. Other codes run perfectly but this one would not.... the error I am getting now Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

Comment: I have tested it and it's working - try *re-building* it and *re-run* your app.

Comment: @Draven The information that you get an `InvocationTargetException` is practically useless. Every exeption happening in `start` is wrapped in this kind of exception. The part of the stacktrace that's actually interesting is the part starting at the last `Caused by`; this should also mention lines in your own code...

Comment: @fabian, thanks for the info, I can post what is cause by

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
 at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)

Comment: @ShekharRai *"Adding children with `pane.getChildren().addAll`" on a `GridPane` is irrelevant and will be ignored"* That part of the sentence is wrong. Adding children to a `GridPane` can very well be done; the only downside is that you cannot specify the layout parameters in the same go, 0 will be used for indices that are not specified and 1 for spans that are not specified. You can however use static methods to set those, e.g. `GridPane.setRowIndex(child, index)`; In fact using `GridPane` from fxml is only possible because of that fact.

Comment: still no result

Comment: @Draven I don't believe you've posted the _root_ cause. See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627).